# Spotfire Ordered Row Identification with RowID

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a large data table and am wanting to use the RowID function to use a sequencer.

However, I realized that when I do this, the RowID() is not tied to any specific order. Is there a way to use the RowID function OVER one of my filtering variables, or is there a way to have a ranked RowId ranked by Variable A, then Var B, then VarC?

Comment: I think you want RANK or RANKREAL instead

Comment: RowID is ordered in the order of the data as it was read from the data source, there is no way to change that. If you tell more about your problem than we may help you with other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a calculated column as  RANK([varA],[varB],[varC]). This will do the same as "RowID() OVER ([varA],[varB],[varC])" would have done.